# Emulate "Save Edits" GUI button via an ArcPy script in ArcGIS Pro 3.0

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, editing

I am using ArcGIS Pro v3.0

I have written a script to perform a set of toolbox operations on a couple of layers in my map.

One thing I noticed was that more often than not I forget to save my edits before running the script and I get some errors as some of the operations cannot be performed whilst the layers are being edited.

What I have tried to do is therefore to find the command that emulates the following GUI "Save" button:

[image]

I've had a look at the [ArcPy editor page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/editor.htm), without success.

Here is the code I have written to try and save any unsaved edits and stop editing:

```
# I access the editor
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace)
# I check if the editor is currently active
if edit.isEditing == True
   # If it is I close the editing session and save any outstanding changes
   edit.stopEditing(True)
```

But when I check for `edit.isEditing` it always returns `False` even when I clearly have some unsaved edits.

The workspace I use to instantiate the editor is the database where the layer files are stored. I tried specifying the individual features but that doesn't seem to work.

Ultimately the state I'm trying to get to is the one I get once I clicked the "Save" button above, followed by the "OK" on the pop-up below which results in all edits being saved and the "Save" button being greyed out.

[image]

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a feature class and a layer in order to make progress with ArcPy (layer files are *not* stored in a database). You haven't provided any code, so it's difficult to help. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: @Vince I have added the code I tried using. As you can see it is pretty simple but it seems not to work. In a sense I am not surprised the Editor call seems to create an instance of the Editor class. But I haven't found a way of accessing any existing instances that could then be checked and closed.

Comment: Have you tried using the [IsBeingEdited](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/isbeingedited.htm#:~:text=The%20following%20code%20checks%20if%20the%20workspace%20is,arcpy.IsBeingEdited%20%28arcpy.env.workspace%29%3A%20edit%20%3D%20arcpy.da.Editor%20%28arcpy.env.workspace%29%20edit.startEditing%20%28%29) method? You're creating a new Editor and this method does not require it.

Comment: Thanks @evv_gis, that sounds like exactly what I need... even if I couldn't terminate the edit session, I could still prevent the script from running and give the user a warning. Unfortunately it isn't available in ArcGIS 3.0, only in 3.1

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Add `edit.startEditing(False, False)` after declaring your editor.

### More details

From [this doc on `arcpy.da.Editor`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/editor.htm):

```py
editor = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
editor.startEditing(with_undo=False, multiuser_mode=True)
editor.startOperation()

# Do things here.

editor.stopOperation()
editor.stopEditing(save_changes=True)
```

It would appear that you are missing `startEditing()` and possibly `startOperation()` (see below).

### Things to look out for

I have found the following caveats using 10.8:

- The documentation on `with_undo` and `multiuser_mode` doesn't make sense to me regardless how many times I read it. What **has** worked is building a little harness around it and testing all the possibilities (luckily there aren't many) until I find the one that works.
- The `startOperation()` and `stopOperation()` calls raise exceptions for me more often than they make a valid and positive difference. My current standard practice is to ignore them when initially writing the code, then add them later *if necessary.*
- **The context operations do not seem to work.** You may be tempted to use `with arcpy.da.Editor()` but this always causes strange errors with misleading messages for me.
- In many situations where I thought I would need an edit session and even many when I was told by others (who know) that I would definitely need an edit session, I did not need an edit session. You may try your edits without and see if they work. Certainly versioning plays a critical role in this but it looks like you may be using an FGDB, which would put you clearly in the *maybe sometimes* realm.
- This pattern works best for me:

  ```py
  try:
      editor = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
      editor.startEditing(with_undo=False, multiuser_mode=False)

      # Do things here.

  finally:
      try:
          editor.stopEditing(save_changes=True)
      finally:
          pass
  ```

  There is [some discussion](https://peps.python.org/pep-0463/) about using your method of checking for a condition, *versus* this one of just trying the operation and letting it run if it works. [Python convention](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP) seems to prefer the latter over the former. The latter certainly seems to be easier in this context.

I hope that something in there solves your problem.